# Add permissions to the default group in django using post_save signals

Tags: django, permissions

I created two groups using post_save signals in django. My default groups name are: 'members' and 'managers'. Now I try to add default permissions to the default gropu 'members'. So far I did:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def add_to_default_permission(sender, **kwargs):
    members = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        permission1 = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add person')
        permission2 = Permission.objects.get(name='Can change person')
        permission3 = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add child')
        permission4 = Permission.objects.get(name='Can change child')
        permission5 = Permission.objects.get(name='Can delete child')
        members.permissions.add(permission1, permission2,permission3,permission4,permission5)
```

But when I tried to create superuser, it gives errors:

```
in add_to_default_permission
        members.permissions.add(permission1, permission2,permission3,permission4,permission5)
    AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'permissions'
```

How could I fix this error. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
members, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='members)
members.permission.add(your permissions)
```

Comment: I want to add permissions to group 'members' not any specific user. The users belong to this group will automatically inherit default permissions.

Comment: hey please check this now

Comment: How do I add my all permissions?

Comment: This gives following errors: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'permission'